# How to convince openSUSE Tumbleweed to NOT throw out NVIDIA display driver on updates

Tags: drivers, nvidia, opensuse, display, graphics

I installed [NVIDIA's *Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver*](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/156163/en-us/) for my Laptop's *NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970M/PCIe/SSE2* since I had issues with display a few weeks ago (I don't remember exactly which; I think it was with my [three] multi-monitor setting).

Since then every second update or so (and they are presented almost daily with Tumbleweed) this driver is thrown out, TW boots into shell and I have to run:

```
$ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.85.05.run
```

there.

What can I do to avoid this (apart from changing to a different distribution, which I'm already thinking of)?

#### UPDATE 1

It became even worse today:

[image: Error on NVIDIA driver install]

So I'm stuck on the shell. That's maximum annoyance.

`/var/log/nvidia-installer.log` contains 72,386 lines including:

- a lot `: error: assignment of read-only member 'vm_flags' ...`
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQAWB.jpg (too large to insert here as image)

Thank you, SUSE, for nothing! ☹️

#### UPDATE 2

I performed what's described in [*SDB:NVIDIA drivers*](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_drivers):

```
# zypper in nvidia-video-G06
# zypper in nvidia-gl-G06
```

[GL worked at the second try only. There was a `curl` error at the first try.]

```
# shutdown -r now
```

Still booting into shell AND THERE IS NO `/var/lib/nvidia-pubkeys` as mentioned in [**Secureboot**](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_drivers#Secureboot)! There is `/var/lib/nvidia` with no sub-dir and the files:

```
100
...
104
*105
*...
*108
dirs
log
```

What now? ☹️

#### UPDATE 3

I tried installing the latest NVIDIA driver before and after **UPDATE 2**:

[image: Error at latest NVIDIA driver install]

Really, what now? ☹️

---

PS: If you decide to start fiddling around with Linux be sure to always(!) have a second working(!) computer with Internet access(!) at hand. Otherwise you're going to be lost completely sooner or later. That's sad, but that's my experience over the decades since my first own kernel compilation of Slackware ~30 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since then every second update or so (and they are presented almost daily with Tumbleweed) this driver is thrown out, TW boots into shell and I have to run:

You described a "the hard way" setup as in https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_the_hard_way

The easy and most common is to setup using a repository as in https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_drivers

First uninstall the hard way:

```
sh <NVIDIA*.run> --uninstall
```

Then install kernel module and drivers:

```
zypper in nvidia-video-G06 nvidia-gl-G06 nvidia-driver-G06-kmp
```

Specifying the closed-source kernel module might avoid the open-source module being installed which doesn't support your graphics card.

You also described 2 network issues / incomplete downloads, that's a separate issue to look into. For instance, after downloading a package as described in update 3, you are expected to run an integrity check to verify the download is complete. zypper does that automatically.